# Can I be awarded the same badge multiple times per hour?

Tags: support, badges

I'm talking about the Announcer badge. I shared a lot of links to questions, and I think that more than 25 different IP addresses have visited some of them, but I only was awarded one badge. Is it not possible to be awarded the same badge multiple times per hour/day?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think the badge can be awarded multiple times *for the same link*.  Otherwise, a link that was visited by 2,500 people would result in 100 announcer badges.

Comment: i meant links @NobodyNada

Comment: @Veltro Do you know for sure they've been visited by more than 25 IPs? :p

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but I think it has @JonClements

Comment: yes i'm sure @JonClements

Comment: Sure, people are awarded multiple badges per hour all the time. You just haven't met the criteria for those questions yet.